# Is 松佳 a name in Japanese?

Tags: names

Is 松佳(まつか) a girl's name in Japanese?  Does it sound traditional?  What image does it give?
I found this on the site https://b-name.jp/ but seems like no one is using it.

Comment: This is my subjective opinion, but 松佳 is a rare but totally reasonable name for a girl. Apparently there are some real female people with this name on Facebook. Yes it sounds traditional If I have to choose between modern and traditional.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

松 and 佳 have positive meanings so both are very common for girl's name such as 松子, 佳恵, 由佳, etc. I think 佳 is rather than 松 nowadays. But, the combination of 松+佳 in single name is not traditional for girl's. (To be honest, I've never seen and couldn't read it as まつか at first)